# Why I can't get the frame immediately when I use masonry?

Tags: ios, objective-c

**This code:**

```
[self.scrollView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.mas_equalTo(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0));
}];
NSLog(@"%@", self.scrollView);
```

result is:`<UIScrollView: 0x7faad400cc00; frame = (0 0; 0 0)`

**However this code:**

```
[self.scrollView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.mas_equalTo(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0));
}];
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"%@", self.scrollView);
});
```

result is:`<UIScrollView: 0x7ff8d1043200; frame = (0 0; 375 667);`

**Why I can't get the frame immediately but I can get after 0.1 second?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Masonry is a wrapper for autolayouts, and autolayouts calculate itself frame in `- (void)layoutSubviews;` method, and only after that u can get frames of all views.

masonry methods `mas_makeConstraints` and similar just setups Constraints no more.

And if you need update constraints you must call `mas_remakeConstraints:` its just update constraits, for update Frames of views, we must call method `setNeedsLayout` for setup a flag about recalculation in next Display cycle, and if we want update frames immediately we must call `layoutIfNeeded` method.

Comment: Is the Display Cycle from `viewWillLayoutSubviews` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: @无夜之星辰 after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` you can get correct `frame`s

Comment: @无夜之星辰 if you ask to me about what is Display Cycle, then its mechanism for a refresh your screen. Whole app working in a big loop for scan sensors, for refresh views, to detect and push notifications. And Display Cycle just ask in each loop, which views needs to be redrawn by methods 'setNeedsDisplay', or which view needs to be layout by `setNeedsLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because you are changing your view's constraints/layout in a block. If you understand what a block does completely, you will know the answer to your question.

The program will run from the first line of your code, and go through the `NSLog` method line, and the codes inside the block will either be called first before the `NSLog` line ,Or after the `NSLog` line. As what you've said, you can get the frame after **0.1 second**. Again that's because the codes inside the block finishes slower than the `NSLog` line.

Comment: Blocks don't necessarily "finish slower" than other chunks of code. In this case, I'd expect that Masonry runs that block immediately, so that it *does* finish before the NSLog line. The reason the frame isn't correct immediately is instead that the Auto Layout system needs a layout pass before it translates new constraints into frames, as @Bimawa suggests, and 0.1 seconds is enough to run one of these passes.

Comment: I just explained stuff to the OP in the simplest way I could.

Comment: It has nothing to do with block.